# check if window with view is open

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have the following code:

```
#pragma mark Barcodescanner
- (void)barcodeScanner:(id)sender {

UIWindow *window = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate.window;

//UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, window.frame.size.width, window.frame.size.height)];

UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake((window.frame.size.width - 600) / 2, (window.frame.size.height - 400) / 2, 600, 400)];

//Here it should be checked if the scanner is open, if it is open, the scanner should closed, if the scanner is not open, the scanner should be open
[window addSubview:view];

self.scanner = [[MTBBarcodeScanner alloc] initWithPreviewView:view];


[MTBBarcodeScanner requestCameraPermissionWithSuccess:^(BOOL success) {
    if (success) {

        [self.scanner startScanningWithResultBlock:^(NSArray *codes) {

            [self.scanner stopScanning];

            AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject *code = [codes firstObject];

            NSRange rangeTypeOfEngine = NSMakeRange(0, 2);
            NSString *typOfEngine = [code.stringValue substringWithRange:rangeTypeOfEngine];

            NSRange rangeSerialNumberOfEngine = NSMakeRange(2, code.stringValue.length - 2);
            NSString *serialNumberOfEngine = [code.stringValue substringWithRange:rangeSerialNumberOfEngine];

            NSNumberFormatter *f = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
            f.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle;
            NSNumber *myNumber = [f numberFromString:typOfEngine];


            NSString *nameOfEngine;

            switch ([myNumber intValue]) {
                case 10:
                case 11:
                case 12:
                case 13:
                    nameOfEngine = @"T100";
                    break;
                default:
                    nameOfEngine = @"noname";
                    serialNumberOfEngine = @"";
                    break;
            }


            Geraet *newGeraet = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Geraet" inManagedObjectContext:MOC];
            newGeraet.einsatzbericht = self.einsatzbericht;
            newGeraet.bezeichnung = nameOfEngine;
            newGeraet.nummer = serialNumberOfEngine;

            [MOC save:nil];

            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kUpdateListOfDevices object:nil];

            [view removeFromSuperview];


            /*
                NSArray *codeArray = [code.stringValue componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];

                [view removeFromSuperview];

                DLAVAlertView *alertView = [[DLAVAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Fehler" message:@"Ungültiger Code" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
                [alertView show];
            */
        }];

    } else {
            [view removeFromSuperview];
    }
}];
}
```

I add the full function to see what it would do.

My problem is, when someone click on the camperabutton for open the scanner, he couldn't cancel the scanner until he scan any barcode.

Comment: what is the problem? describe

Answer (score 0):

Camera and Alert View open in new window instead of your app window.

Comment: But its only as Window over my app, not as a single window

Comment: what do you want as final result? do you want custom camera in your app or something different?

Comment: I use the camera as barcodescanner. And when it detect any barcode in the camera i got the barcodenumber as result and the camera would be stopped.

Comment: what do you want to do? What i understand is you are using a bar scanner and if barcode not find it will not cancel scanner